# Constraint added

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to Database.I have created a table `"Master_User"` using Microsoft `SQL server Management Studio`.

```
USE [MXDEN]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [PK_Master_User]    Script Date: 01/14/2014 11:21:27 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Master_User] 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Master_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH 
 (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY])
GO
```

Can anyone help me understading why is this automatically created.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is your question why is this script generated?

Comment: It was created as you put ID column to be primary key in your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is why is this script generated, it's likely that you have "Auto generate change scripts" enabled in your options.

Depending on your version of SQL Server, if you go in to Tools > Options, then in the dialog navigate to: Designers, there is a checkbox that configures this: `Auto generate change scripts`.

If this is ticked, any time you make a change, a script will be generated for the change. Just untick this if you don't want it to generate scripts.

[image]